# Error: new columns would leave holes after existing columns

Tags: r

Ok so I am trying to conditionally adjust certain values in a given column in a dataframe.
My code looks like this:

```
adjust_LAP<-function(LA){
  x<-LAP[LAP$LA.ID==LA,]
  y<-known[known[,1]==LA,]

  LAP_adj[LAP_adj$LA.ID==LA,LAP_adj$T1_1AGE0_4M]<-x$T1_1AGE0_4M-y$T1_1AGE0_4M
  return(LAP_adj)
}

LAP_adj<-LAP
y<-sapply(known[,1],adjust_LAP)
```

Basically - both known and LAP have the same columns. known includes a row only for a subset of the rows in LAP however - including a unique identifier (LA in LAP and known[,1]). Because they are not necessarily in the same order, I am subsetting each data frame to include only the relevant row before adjusting specific columns. However known has less rows than LAP as not every row needs adjusting.

I'm getting the error "new columns would leave holes after existing columns" and I can't figure out why.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: do you just want to replace the column T1_1AGE0_4M with x$T1_1AGE0_4M-y$T1_1AGE0_4M ? I dont understand why it is "- y$T1_1AGE0_4M" which is in known. Could you detail a bit more? maybe add some sample data?

Comment: Not surprising that this is causing difficulties. You are sending a single column (`known[,1]`) to a function and then within the function are setting `y` to be the rows where the columns `==LA`, which couldn't be more than one column and the logic becomes too complicated to parse. You should write down in natural language (using no indefinite pronouns) the steps to be performed and transfer that to the question by editing. Sample data would be necessary, not just optional.